# AdWords API : client list for non MCC account

Tags: c#, xml, soap, google-ads-api

I want to get a list of AdWords clients assigned to authenticated account (i use OAuth).

First attempt was to use ServicedAccountService and this XML request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestHeader xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201109">
      <developerToken xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201109">[[DEV_TOKEN]]</developerToken>
    </RequestHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <get xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201109">
      <selector>
        <enablePaging>false</enablePaging>
      </selector>
    </get>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But it works only for MCC accounts. For regular google account i got empty dataset

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <ResponseHeader xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109" xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201109">
      <ns2:requestId>0004bc71cee633d00aecb0aa000060ca</ns2:requestId>
      <ns2:serviceName>ServicedAccountService</ns2:serviceName>
      <ns2:methodName>get</ns2:methodName>
      <ns2:operations>0</ns2:operations>
      <ns2:responseTime>230</ns2:responseTime>
      <ns2:units>0</ns2:units>
    </ResponseHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <getResponse xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201109" xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109">
      <rval>
        <accounts>
          <customerId>0</customerId>
          <canManageClients>false</canManageClients>
        </accounts>
      </rval>
    </getResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I googled a lot, and finally [found](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adwords-api/RyZGxJ4oLAQ/hQgUywTEJZcJ) that i can use other XML (InfoService) for both MCC and non MCC accounts.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestHeader xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/info/v201109">
      <developerToken xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109">[[DEV_TOKEN]]</developerToken>
    </RequestHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <get xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/info/v201109">
      <selector>
        <dateRange>
          <min xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109">[[START_DATE]]</min>
          <max xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109">[[END_DATE]]</max>
        </dateRange>
        <includeSubAccounts>true</includeSubAccounts>
        <apiUsageType>UNIT_COUNT_FOR_CLIENTS</apiUsageType>
      </selector>
    </get>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But data returned is incorrect - not all accounts are listed. Or no data returned at all.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <ResponseHeader xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109" xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/info/v201109">
            <ns2:requestId>0004bc7121a910e80a97030d000051e7</ns2:requestId>
            <ns2:serviceName>InfoService</ns2:serviceName>
            <ns2:methodName>get</ns2:methodName>
            <ns2:operations>1</ns2:operations>
            <ns2:responseTime>1206</ns2:responseTime>
            <ns2:units>1</ns2:units>
        </ResponseHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <getResponse xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109" xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/info/v201109">
            <rval>
                <cost>0</cost>
            </rval>
        </getResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there any other way to get client list for AdWords account? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also encountered this problem, and can confirm that it's not the correct behaviour of the ServicedAccountService; it's a ["known issue that will be resolved in future"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/adwords-api/ServicedAccountService/adwords-api/ZE58G9wSfh8/DSq4R2fuTB8J): If you link your basic account to an MCC, then you can authenticate with the basic account and use the ServicedAccountService to obtain the account details, but if the account isn't linked then you'll get this problem.

If you just want to obtain the customer id for an account, you can also use the [InfoService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/InfoService.html), which doesn't suffer from the same issue.

Comment: last xml in my question it's a reply from InfoService. It also works incorrect - it not show all accounts, only that were accessed via API, and this is not what i want to reach.

Comment: You need to use the ServicedAccountService for an MCC account, and the InfoService for a normal account. I call the ServicedAccountService first, then make an InfoService call if there's a zero in the id field. It's just a workaround until the issue gets fixed by Google.